# PrintWriter doesn't replace after split but appends instead

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader, printwriter

I am trying to add +1 every time male button is selected.

```
    if ( a == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION ){
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    String[] parts = line.split(":");
                    int count = ((Integer.parseInt(parts[1])+1));
                    String temp = "" + count;
                    parts[1] = parts[1].replaceAll("[0-9]", temp);
                    pw.print(parts[1]);
        }
    }pw.close();
```

In my docx file, Male:0 is already written and if I click the button Male, it would add +1 to Male which would make it Male:1. But what happens is it writes instead of adding. It prints Male:01 instead of my desired output.

Comment: Use [0-9]+ not [0-9] , see if it works

Comment: @JClassic It works! But now it appends a whole string of Male:1 to Male:0

Comment: Where is pw declared

Comment: Inside main and above the if statement

`FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Tally.txt", true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);`

Comment: @JClassic oops sorry. forgot to tag